# PHP Using classes

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)
>   [PHP: Static and non Static functions and Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361598/php-static-and-non-static-functions-and-objects)
>   [In PHP, whats the difference between :: and -> ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173501/in-php-whats-the-difference-between-and)

I have seen different ways to use classes in PHP e.g.

`$myclass->method()`

or

`MyClass::method()`

what is the difference?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313783/what-is-the-notation-in-php-used-for

Comment: also see: [In PHP, whats the difference between :: and -> ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173501/in-php-whats-the-difference-between-and)

Answer (score 2):

From your example, $myclass appears to be an instance of the class MyClass and you are invoking an instance method. Instance methods are invoked from instances of a class.

In the second example, method appears to be a [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) method of the class. A static method is invoked at the class level, no instance is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The first is calling method from an object, so you would have done `$myclass = new MyClass()`, the constructor (`__construct()`) was called, etc.

The second one is a static call: no object is instantiated, and it cannot use `$this` references. Static variables are the same all over the place btw, while non-static variables are specific to the object they're in.

Although the question is closed, you might find some good info on static here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090994/what-does-the-static-keyword-mean-in-oop

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use `$myclass->method()` you first have to create an instance of the class.

`$myclass = new myClass();`

The second is used to access the moethod without first creating an instance.