# What does :: mean in php?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the “::” notation in php used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313783/what-is-the-notation-in-php-used-for)

I noticed this code while modifying a friends code and noticed this piece of code: TestPages::LoadMenu();

what does :: mean in php?

A great answer would mean a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: Please go back and accept the best answers to your questions (i.e. click the big check mark to the left of the best answers). It will give you +2 rep for each one that you mark and generally improve the information on this site. It's the right thing to do. Do it.

Comment: dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's the 'Scope Resolution Operator'.

> The Scope Resolution Operator (also called Paamayim Nekudotayim) or in
>   simpler terms, the double colon, is a token that allows access to
>   static, constant, and overridden properties or methods of a class.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Comment: Paamayim Nekudotayim literally translates to "double colon", just a little added info for those curious.

Comment: ... in Hebrew, to add a little more for the even more curious.

Comment: @Cyclone and Marc B because of people like you is why I love this website <3

Answer (score 10):

In layman terms it is used to call `static` Methods of a Class.

In your example, `LoadMenu()` is a static function of the `TestPages` class.

This means that you do not have to create an instance of a `TestPages` to call `LoadMenu()`

Answer (score 5):

It is used to access static methods of class, static variables and constants

[Read more](http://php.net/%3A%3A)

Answer (score 3):

It means static class member access, in this case static method invocation.

Answer (score 1):

It's used to access class methods / properties:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Comment: An important distinction to make to those that see this answer in the future, is that it is used to reference ***`static`*** members of a class, not an instantiated object's members.

Comment: Attention! Please read **@jondavidjohn's** comment before you read this answer.